# Deciding the aromaticity of two napthalene-like rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

Why is the first compound aromatic and the second compound non-aromatic?

In the first compound, the left side of the ring is aromatic but the right side isn't.
Second compound satisfies all the conditions of aromaticity but why is it non-aromatic?

[image]

Comment: I think there's something to do with planarity. I don't think the second compound exists in the form you drew it in. Did you think about that factor?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75688/is-1-2-dihydronaphthalene-aromatic and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86734/aromatic-compounds